# finding a point in line

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

$A$ and $C$ are two end points of a line where $A=(-10,-4);  C=(8,5)$. point $B$ is on the line $AC$ having coordinate $(-1,y)$ ,find $y$.

Is there any general formula to find a point of a line you know like above question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the slope formula $$m = \dfrac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$ with the first two points: $$(x_1, y_1) = A = (-10,-4); (x_2, y_2) = C = (8,5)$$

Then we find that the slope is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then you can replace either $C$ or $A$ in the slope formula with $B$ and solve for the missing component.

Answer (score 0):

The points are points of the line $-x+2y=2$

or

$y=1+\dfrac{x}{2}$

for $x=-1$ is $(-1, \dfrac{1}{2})$

Comment: "The points are points of the line..." - care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Equation of the straight line $AC$ is $$\frac{y+4}{5+4} = \frac{x+10}{8+10}$$ 
For $B(-1,y)$ we have $$\frac{y+4}{5+4} = \frac{-1+10}{8+10}$$
$$\implies y=\frac{1}{2}$$